# MySQL 5.7.12 default date format yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMdd

Tags: mysql, date

Both the SQLs below provide the same output in MySQL.

```
select * from tbl1 where BATCH_DATE = '20180404'

select * from tbl1 where BATCH_DATE = '2018-04-04'
```

So can we consider both the date formats are default in MySQL?

Please explain the catches respective of MySQL, if any. 
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: [9.1.3 Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Comment: If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp before the comparison is performed https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: MySQL Fun Fact: `select @@global.date_format` returns `%Y-%m-%d` so it could be argued that's the default. The format is however actually hard-coded and it cannot be changed so it could be argued it isn't a *default* anyway.